# Shopify Dashing: CoffeeScript not showing X axis as months

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, sinatra, rickshaw, dashing

Similar to: [Not able to display Month names on Rickshaw Graph on Coffeescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765960/not-able-to-display-month-names-on-rickshaw-graph-on-coffeescript)

Although, this question is similar to the above, I have already tried the given answer on that question and I still am unable to change the numerical values along the 'X' axis into month names

**Code that is relevant from RickshawGraph.coffee:**

```
xAxisOptions = new Rickshaw.Fixtures.Time()
time = xAxisOptions.unit('month')

x_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time(graph: graph, timeUnit: time, timeFixture: xAxisOptions)

y_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y(graph: graph, tickFormat: Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.format)
```

I'd like to be able to show month names instead of numbers... Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983765/dashing-problems-using-rickshaw-with-one-widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's how I got at least the dates to show, although another issue has cropped up because of it:

**New Code**

```
format =  (d) ->
enddate = new Date()
startdate = new Date()
startdate.setMonth(startdate.getMonth() - 12)

d = d3.time.months(startdate,enddate)

x_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X(graph: graph, pixelsPerTick: 1000, tickFormat: format)
```

Here's the link to the other issue (Which is related to this, but different):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141212/coffeescript-dashing-rickshaw-graph-range-of-dates-parse